# Return array from Linq SQL query on 80 million row table using EFCore

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm querying a SQL database using Linq and Entity Framework Core in a Razorpages project to generate a residency plot, [here's one that I made earlier.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USPzP.jpg)

I'm struggling to optimise this query despite many attempts and iterations, it is slow and it often times out. I need the final array of the Count() values that make up each square of the residency plot and am not interested in the raw data.

The data are from a table with ~80 million rows and I've found solutions from SO which might work with fewer entries but that aren't suitable in this use case (generally searching Linq, group, join). I think the problem is the combination of filters, groups and joins followed by a count occurring server-side without first downloading the raw data.

Reviewing the SQL command in SSMS (pulled from LINQPad) it is very poorly optimised - I can post this if it would be useful but it's 236 lines long made up of repeated sections.

The Linq I've hobbled together performs the required operation in the 4 steps outlined here.

**Step 1** (rows between a certain time, with a certain LocationTypeId, and a channelId = engSpeed):

```
var speedRows = context.TestData
.Where(a => a.Time >= start
&& a.Time < end
&& a.LocationTypeId == 3
&& a.channelId == 7)
.Select(s => new
{
    s.Time,
    s.ChannelValue
})
.Distinct();
```

**Step 2** (rows with a channelId = torque):

```
var torqueRows = context.TestData
.Where(a => a.LocationTypeId == 3
&& a.channelId == 8)
.Select(s => new
{
    s.Time,
    s.ChannelValue
})
.Distinct();
```

**Step 3** (join the speed and torque rows from **Step 1** and **Step 2** on Time):

```
var joinedRows = speedRows.Join(torqueRows, arg => arg.Time, arg => arg.Time,
    (speed, torque) => new
    {
        Id = speed.Time,
        Speed = Convert.ToDouble(speed.ChannelValue),
        Torque = Convert.ToInt16(torque.ChannelValue)
    });
```

**Step 4** (create the dynamic groupings using the joined table from **Step 3**):

```
var response = (from a in joinedRows
            group a by (a.Torque / 100) into torqueGroup
            orderby torqueGroup.Key
            select new
            {
                TorqueBracket = $"{100 * torqueGroup.Key} <> {100 + (100 * torqueGroup.Key)}",
                TorqueMin = 100 * torqueGroup.Key,
                TorqueMax = 100 + (100 * torqueGroup.Key),
                Speeds = (from d in torqueGroup
                            group d by (Math.Floor((d.Speed) / 500)) into speedGroup
                            orderby speedGroup.Key
                            select new
                            {
                                SpeedBracket = $"{500 * speedGroup.Key} <> {500 + (500 * speedGroup.Key)}",
                                SpeedMin = 500 * (int)speedGroup.Key,
                                SpeedMax = 500 + (500 * (int)speedGroup.Key),
                                Minutes = speedGroup.Count()
                            })
            }).ToList();
```

I could be missing something obvious but I've tried many attempts and this is the best I've got.

The `TestData` class:

```
public partial class TestData {
    public int LiveDataId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Time { get; set; }
    public int? LocationTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? TestNo { get; set; }
    public int? LogNo { get; set; }
    public int? LiveDataChannelId { get; set; }
    public decimal? ChannelValue { get; set; }
    public virtual LiveDataChannelNames LiveDataChannel { get; set; }
    public virtual LocationType LocationType { get; set; }
}
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to take a look at how your data is indexed in SQL Server.  Have you indexed TestData?  If so, what columns?  Time, LocationTypeId, channelId ?

Comment: ORMs like EF are designed for persisting and retrieving small to moderate amounts of data, they are **not** intended to be used for complex scenarios because they end up generating monstrous, convoluted and poorly-performing SQL queries - as you've already seen. I can guarantee you that almost any SQL you write to achieve what you need will be shorter, simpler, and perform better - probably by orders of magnitude - than the best that EF can do. So write a stored procedure or view to do what you need, then call it from EF. (And don't forget about indexes as @MarkMcWhirter noted.)

Comment: @IanKemp It's true in general and easy to be said, but I'm wondering how you would write SQL query which returns sub record list per parent record. You've probably return a giant flat record set (with union columns from the two, with parent values repeating) and then transform it client side. ORM should be able to do such things, the problem is EF Core doesn't, especially with `GroupBy` queries - most likely retrieving all the data and performing the grouping part in memory.

Comment: @Tom, what EF Core version are you using?

Comment: How many rows are in `speedRows` and `torqueRows`?

Comment: @MarkMcWhirter I have Non-Unique, Non-Clustered indexes on Time, LocationTypeId and LiveDataChannelId.

Comment: @IanKemp thank you for the tips. I have stumbled across but not played with stored procedures for long.. I may have to concede this point to them though and get used to writing some SQL

Comment: @IvanStoev 2.2.6

Comment: @NetMage This can vary drastically, the example image I used there would be about 30,000 (1 entry for each 1 point on the chart). This can exceed 100,000 for a particularly active result

Comment: @Tom This means most likely your query is evaluated client side (and in 3.0+ would simply throw runtime exception). Post your class so we can run the query and see what can be done.

Comment: @IvanStoev assuming you mean the LiveData class? If so:

public partial class LiveData
{
    public int LiveDataId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Time { get; set; }
    public int? LocationTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? TestNo { get; set; }
    public int? LogNo { get; set; }
    public int? LiveDataChannelId { get; set; }
    public decimal? ChannelValue { get; set; }

    public virtual LiveDataChannelNames LiveDataChannel { get; set; }
    public virtual LocationType LocationType { get; set; }
}

Comment: LiveData === TestData. I renamed it in the comment for clarity

Comment: For larger data either use SQL[Create View/Stored Proc ,Write all logics inside SQL]  or Dapper

Comment: I literally hve to blow some peoples illusions but even Ef 5 years ago could easily handle millions of objects. I have repeatedly used it to load or filter large amounts. THe problem is that EfCore is way behind in SQL translations and some oprations - even in 3.1 - still suck in a tremendous amount of data to do client side grouping. 2.2.6 - as used here - is amazingly bad in this regard. 3.1 is better, though still a ecade gbehind Ef (non core). Best goal would be likely to go to Ef 6.4 (non core) - this one at least WORKS. Pulling a million rows is small change. Group by, union, intersect

Comment: We ahve non core logic where we use ef to generate pages long sql with many unions and intersects and it works amazingly fast. The problem is not "orm in general" but "efcore STILL has SERIOUS problems with anything that is not a simple select".

Comment: @TomTom You could well be right, I think I'm stuck with EFCore 2.2.6 for this project as it's the latest which is compatible with ASP.Net Core, I should have mentioned that. But thank you, I'll use your tips for next project.

Comment: @Tom Note that Ef NON core is ALSO compatible with ASP.NE core and can be installed in dotnetcore 3.1 - ef version 6.4 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answers posted here were helpful in making me understand the intricacies of the problem (thank you to all that posted) they did not work with Entity Framework Core version 2.2.6. I've managed to get reasonable and stable performance with the C# code below.

Crucially in steps 1 and 2 the *.ToList()* stops timeouts on longer queries by (I assume) dividing the enumeration of results, possibly with a small time penalty. Also the *(double)* and *(short)* conversions are performed server-side natively as opposed to *Convert.ToDouble* and *Convert.ToInt16* respectively.

**Step 1** (rows between a certain time, with a certain LocationTypeId, and a channelId = engSpeed):

```
var speedRows = context.TestData
.Where(a => a.Time >= start
&& a.Time < end
&& a.LocationTypeId == 3
&& a.channelId 7)
.Select(s => new
{
    s.Time,
    ChannelValue = (double)s.ChannelValue
})
.Distinct().ToList();
```

**Step 2** (rows with a channelId = torque):

```
var torqueRows = context.TestData
.Where(a => a.LocationTypeId == 3
&& a.channelId == 8)
.Select(s => new
{
    s.Time,
    ChannelValue = (short)s.ChannelValue
})
.Distinct().ToList();
```

**Step 3** (join the speed and torque rows from **Step 1** and **Step 2** on Time):

```
var joinedRows = speedRows.Join(torqueRows, arg => arg.Time, arg => arg.Time,
    (speed, torque) => new
    {
        Id = speed.Time,
        Speed = speed.ChannelValue,
        Torque = torque.ChannelValue
    });
```

**Step 4** (group the rows into keyed groups)

```
var groupedData = joinedRows
    .GroupBy(arg => new { TorqueGroupKey = (arg.Torque / 100), SpeedGroupKey = Math.Floor((arg.Speed) / 500) })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.TorqueGroupKey,
        g.Key.SpeedGroupKey,
        Minutes = g.Count()
    });
```

**Step 5** (create the dynamic groupings using groupedData from **Step 4**):

```
var response = (from a in groupedData.AsEnumerable()
            group a by a.TorqueGroupKey into torqueGroup
            orderby torqueGroup.Key
            select new ResidencySqlResult
            {
                TorqueBracket = $"{100 * torqueGroup.Key} <> {100 + (100 * torqueGroup.Key)}",
                TorqueMin = 100 * torqueGroup.Key,
                TorqueMax = 100 + (100 * torqueGroup.Key),
                Speeds = (from d in torqueGroup
                          orderby d.SpeedGroupKey
                          select new Speeds
                          {
                              SpeedBracket = $"{500 * d.SpeedGroupKey} <> {500 + (500 * d.SpeedGroupKey)}",
                              SpeedMin = 500 * (int)d.SpeedGroupKey,
                              SpeedMax = 500 + (500 * (int)d.SpeedGroupKey),
                              Minutes = d.Minutes
                          })
            }).ToList();
```

Thank you again to all those that helped out.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the actual generated SQL command is so big - you've probably are checking the SQL command generated by EF6.

The generated SQL by EF Core is not so big, but the problem is that the `Speeds = ...` part of the `GroupBy` cannot be translated to SQL, and is evaluated client side after retrieving all the data from the previous parts of the query.

What you can do is the create intermediate query which retries only the data needed (2 groping keys + count) and the do the rest client side.

First you need to make sure that the subqueries from Step 1, 2 and 3 are translatable to SQL. `Convert.ToDouble` and `Convert.ToInt16` are not translatable, so replace them with casts:

```
Speed = (double)speed.ChannelValue,
Torque = (short)torque.ChannelValue
```

Then split the Step4 on two parts. The server part:

```
var groupedData = joinedRows
    .GroupBy(arg => new { TorqueGroupKey = arg.Torque / 100, SpeedGroupKey = Math.Floor((arg.Speed) / 500) })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.TorqueGroupKey,
        g.Key.SpeedGroupKey,
        Minutes = g.Count()
    });
```

and the client part:

```
var response = (from a in groupedData.AsEnumerable() // <-- swicth to client evaluation
                group a by a.TorqueGroupKey into torqueGroup
                orderby torqueGroup.Key
                select new
                {
                    TorqueBracket = $"{100 * torqueGroup.Key} <> {100 + (100 * torqueGroup.Key)}",
                    TorqueMin = 100 * torqueGroup.Key,
                    TorqueMax = 100 + (100 * torqueGroup.Key),
                    Speeds = (from d in torqueGroup
                              orderby d.SpeedGroupKey
                              select new
                              {
                                  SpeedBracket = $"{500 * d.SpeedGroupKey} <> {500 + (500 * d.SpeedGroupKey)}",
                                  SpeedMin = 500 * (int)d.SpeedGroupKey,
                                  SpeedMax = 500 + (500 * (int)d.SpeedGroupKey),
                                  Minutes = d.Minutes
                              })
                }).ToList();
```

Note that in EF Core 3.0+ you'll be forced to do something like this because implicit client evaluation has been removed.

The generated SQL query now should be something like this:

```sql
  SELECT [t].[ChannelValue] / 100 AS [TorqueGroupKey], FLOOR([t].[ChannelValue] / 500.0E0) AS [SpeedGroupKey], COUNT(*) AS [Minutes]
  FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT [a].[Time], [a].[ChannelValue]
      FROM [TestData] AS [a]
      WHERE ((([a].[Time] >= @__start_0) AND ([a].[Time] < @__end_1)) AND ([a].[LocationTypeId] = 3)) AND ([a].[LiveDataChannelId] = 7)
  ) AS [t]
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT [a0].[Time], [a0].[ChannelValue]
      FROM [TestData] AS [a0]
      WHERE ([a0].[LocationTypeId] = 3) AND ([a0].[LiveDataChannelId] = 8)
  ) AS [t0] ON [t].[Time] = [t0].[Time]
  GROUP BY [t].[ChannelValue] / 100, FLOOR([t].[ChannelValue] / 500.0E0)
```

Comment: Hi @Ivan, thank you very much.

Using LinqPad it's fine but my project complained of converting a decimal to int32 and I needed to add (int) before the ChannelValue lines of both speedRows and torqueRows structures:

.Select(s => new
{
 s.Time,
 ChannelValue = (int)s.ChannelValue
})
.Distinct();

Also the .GroupBy line in groupedData stage acts odd - [screengrab of data structure, torque will never be above 1000](https://imgur.com/a/x9sAbMk)

I will continue to work on it and update with progress, I am off until Friday but will try to reply if you are kind enough to revisit.

Comment: You can also just use Ef (non core) which is available finally in dotnetcore (version 6.4). No clien side evalauation needed, and a lot more works (union, intersect etc.). Ef Core is bound to run into SERIOUS problems - because there still are a LOT of bugs with even generating valid SQL in certain cases. Bugfixe postponed for .NET 5.0 in November.

Comment: @Tom You are welcome. But since I don't have even sample data, all I can do is the check the generated SQL and to make sure the modified LINQ query is equivalent to the original (which is what I already did in the answer).

Comment: @IvanStoev Cheers, I'll mark this answer as correct as I think my particular setup is an anomaly and it works in LinqPad. If I find a solution for my configuration I'll add info here. Thanks again.

Comment: @TomTom many times I was going to argue that EF Core is not that bad. But looks like I'm going to join "the other" (your) side. See [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068) where we wanted to convince them to support some more LINQ operators. At the end they closed it with "we won't do it" because "we don't see a value" !?? "They" don't see a value for "us", huh. Not counting the things they broke and now want us to vote for eventually being put back as "enhancement". And many similar stupid things. "Nice" SQL is a goal, SQL translation is not, no SQL translation is ok.